# Can't delete mysql-server on ubuntu 12.04.5 TLS

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to reinstall mysql-server-5.6, but I can't do anyhing, everytime I have this strange message:

```
root@ps****:/home/nikitasorokin# apt-get remove --purge mysql-server-5.6
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  mysql-client-core-5.6
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove it.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  mysql-server-5.6*
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 941 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 52.5 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 122623 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing mysql-server-5.6 (5.6.25-0ubuntu1) ...
stop: Unknown instance: 
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "stop" failed.
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-5.6 (--purge):
 subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 1
stop: Unknown instance: 
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "stop" failed.
start: Job failed to start
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-5.6
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I know, that the major recommendation is to completely uninstall mysql and all of its components, but I can't do that.
Please, could you consider any solution?

Comment: 12.04? Are you sure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Edit the `post-installation` script

   ```
   sudo nano /var/lib/dpkg/info/mysql-server-5.6.postinst
   ```
2. Search the function

   ```
   invoke() {
       if [ -x /usr/sbin/invoke-rc.d ]; then
           invoke-rc.d mysql $1
       else
           /etc/init.d/mysql $1
       fi
   }
   ```

   and replace with

   ```
   invoke() {
       echo
       #if [ -x /usr/sbin/invoke-rc.d ]; then
       #     invoke-rc.d mysql $1
       #else
       #     /etc/init.d/mysql $1
       #fi
   }
   ```
3. Save the file
4. Edit the `pre-removal` script

   ```
   sudo nano /var/lib/dpkg/info/mysql-server-5.6.prerm
   ```
5. Search the lines

   ```
   if [ -x "/etc/init.d/mysql" ] || [ -e "/etc/init/mysql.conf" ]; then
           invoke-rc.d mysql stop || exit $?
   fi
   ```

   and replace

   ```
   if [ -x "/etc/init.d/mysql" ] || [ -e "/etc/init/mysql.conf" ]; then
           echo
           #invoke-rc.d mysql stop || exit $?
   fi
   ```
6. Edit the `post-removal` script

   ```
   sudo nano /var/lib/dpkg/info/mysql-server-5.6.postrm
   ```
7. Search

   ```
   # New packaging paradigm for my.cnf as of Dec-2014 for sharing mysql
   # variants in Ubuntu.
   case "$1" in
     remove|disappear)
       /usr/share/mysql-common/configure-symlinks remove mysql "$mysql_cfgdir/mysql.cnf"
     ;;
   esac
   ```

   and replace

   ```
   # New packaging paradigm for my.cnf as of Dec-2014 for sharing mysql
   # variants in Ubuntu.
   case "$1" in
     remove|disappear)
       # /usr/share/mysql-common/configure-symlinks remove mysql "$mysql_cfgdir/mysql.cnf"
     ;;
   esac
   ```
8. Save the file and run the command again

   ```
   sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql-server-5.6
   ```

Comment: Unfortunately I have another error now (explained in main post)

Comment: Result: `/var/lib/dpkg/info/mysql-server-5.6.postinst: line 21: syntax error near unexpected token `}'`

Comment: Again changed. My bash skills seems a little bit rusty this evening.

Comment: Was the removal successfully?

Comment: No, I have the same error as it was before...

Comment: `unexpected token`?

Comment: No, this message:

Comment: `Removing mysql-server-5.6 (5.6.25-0ubuntu1) ...
stop: Unknown instance: 
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "stop" failed.
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-5.6 (--purge):
 subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 1

start: Job failed to start
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "start" failed.`

Comment: That's another error. Now in the removal script. Updated my answer

Comment: `Removing mysql-server-5.6 (5.6.25-0ubuntu1) ...

/var/lib/dpkg/info/mysql-server-5.6.postrm: line 53: /usr/share/mysql-common/configure-symlinks: No such file or directory`

Comment: and again updated

Comment: Finally it worked!! Thank you! So now, while installation I still have similar kind of problem:

Comment: `invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "stop" failed.
update-alternatives: error: alternative path /etc/mysql/mysql.cnf doesn't exist
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-5.6 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2`

Comment: Accept the answer with a click on the check mark at the left side of the answer and ask a new question for the installation problem. That's good for your reputation and for mine. **;)**

Comment: Sure! However I can't do that, because I have less then 15 score... I'm a newbie here... So, I will start new question and, possibly, they will give me more points, then I will accept your brilliant solution! :)

Comment: Accepting an answer doesn't need reputation. Upvotes and Downvotes need reputation.